# How to display the last three elements of an array (my example)

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a code that will display the last three elements of an array using for loop. 
1. The arrays size can be modified and the code should cope with that. 
2. The elements should be displayed as they were entered (from left to right).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Task4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {7, -3, 9, -11, 18, 99, 2, 11};
        System.out.println("Current array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("Last three elements of an array: ");
        for (int i = array.length / 2 + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            /*need to display last three elements of an array using for loop.
            the elements should be displayed as they were entered(from left-to-right)*/
        }
    }
}
```

The code works only for this specific array. My question was is there any alternative solutions that will work for any array size?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: The code looks like it will do what you describe. At least for the given array length and even if you change it to be one longer. So, strictly, the code is fine. Please describe in which way you want the behaviour to change.

Comment: Please explain "from left-to-right". In an array there is no left and right, only low index and high index. The output potentially has a left to right meaning, but then "as entered" does not really make sense.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for your response! Yes, the code works perfectly for this specific array, but what if I add more elements or delete some? I am looking for ways in which the code will handle such things. Yes, "from left to right" basically means from low index to high index(e.g  99,2,1 are the last three elements of my array and they should be displayed like that, not like 1,2,99).

Comment: You can start your `i` from where you want in your array, in your case, "array.lenght - 3", then print array[i-1] since array[0] is 1 length.
The order of display depends on the condition. Length-3 to MaxLength (left to right), or MaxLenght to Length -3 (right to left)

Comment: Now that somebody provided a solution for you I am curious about how far away from doing it you were. For that please desribe your understanding of the loop setup `for (int i = array.length / 2 + 1; i < array.length; i++)`. Can you translate that to English? Can you spot the difference between that and "last three elements" from the assignment? If you cannot I recommend to go a few chapters backwards in your textbook and do the exercises again which introduced loops. E.g. the one with the pyramid shape pattern output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to start from the index that equals the length-3 by changing the loop into this :

`for (int i = Math.max(0,array.length-3); i < array.length; i++) {`

Comment: You should probably check also if array length is `>= 3` . Your solution will throw an exception if array length is 2 for example. something like `for (int i = Math.max(0,array.length-3); i < array.length; i++) { `

Comment: thanks to @BuildSlayer the solution now takes care of this situation too

Answer (score 0):

A java stream option here:

```
IntStream.of(array)
        .skip(Math.max(array.length - 3, 0))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Or `Arrays.stream(array, Math.max(0, array.length - 3), array.length)                .forEach(System.out::println)`